# Puppeteer Bot Detection

Tags: puppeteer

I am trying to use puppeteer to login to the nike site but I get an error likely due to anti-bot. I've tried some things to avoid being detected but did not have any luck. Here is my code:

```
//const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const pluginStealth = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
puppeteer.use(pluginStealth());

//Create Sleep function to use in Async/Await function
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
 }

 const randomDelay = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  
(async () => {

  await sleep(1000);

  var browser;

  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
    headless: false,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox', '--disable-web-security'],
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setUserAgent(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
  );
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  });
  await page.goto('https://www.nike.com/us/en_us/e/nike-plus-membership', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  });


    const emailSelector = '.nike-unite-text-input.emailAddress input';
    await page.waitFor(emailSelector);
    await page.waitFor(randomDelay(300, 600));

    const inputs = [emailSelector, '.nike-unite-text-input.password input'];

          await page.type(inputs[0], 'xyz@gmail.com', {
            delay: randomDelay(200, 300),
          });
      
          await page.waitFor(randomDelay(300, 600));
          await page.type(inputs[1], 'XYZDEFEWD!"', {
            delay: randomDelay(200, 300),
          });
      
          const submitBtn = '.nike-unite-submit-button.loginSubmit input';

          await page.waitFor(randomDelay(200, 500));

          await page.click(submitBtn);

})();
```

Is there any way to identify what the website is using to detect that I am using puppeteer?

Answer (score 2):

There could be a full proof solution of avoiding bot detection, but here are the someways you can try

1. Try proxying your IP through multiple countries
2. Try to add random intervals in your n/w calls
3. use random user agents instead of fixed one and also alter the viewport size.

Comment: Complementing the answer above.
Try to make your bot as random as possible. Add random QueryParams to the URL, click random places, use random data, use IP Proxy if possible, try using different resolutions and UserAgents, whatever you can do to make it more realistic. Erase and enter content a few times, add random delay between runs. Do everything to make one execution more different from the other.

Comment: 1. I don't understand how proxies would help if it works fine when I try on localhost without puppeteer. I

Comment: 2. I tried adding random intervals and that doesn't work. Basically if i try to manually log in on the browser launched by puppeteer, it doesn't work. 3. Random user agents does not work either.

Comment: randomizing ip address will help you to stay away from bot detection system and ultimately it will save you from getting banned by target site.

Comment: it wouldn't do anything in this case